# TagLib-sharp Save() in MP3 files without any existing tags

Tags: c#, taglib-sharp

How can I save ID3v2 tags to an mp3 file that is not tagged? When I try, the hard drive begins to buzz and it takes almost 5 minutes or longer until the tags were stored. If the mp3 file already has ID3v2 tags, it goes great.

Comment: 5 minutes for how many files? To insert the tags the files must be rewritten fully unless there is enough space already. Is the time it takes your only issue? Then there is no question. The same effect can be seen with any mp3 tagger esp. when inserting cover art..

Comment: For a single file without cover art. There is enough memory (RAM 16 GB). When I previously using the Windows.Storage MusicProperties one's title to insert it goes very quickly.

Comment: Hm, seems really long. How big is the file? Did you see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284154/taglib-performance-and-crashes-problems)?

Comment: The file is approximately 8 Mb

Comment: Seems harmless enough. Did you try another tagger?

Comment: Yes, with mp3Tag or Helium Music Manager. There it works perfectly.